# Difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference

Tags: c#

A MS help page about the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference seems quite clear to me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx

However, a user comment at the end has confused me somewhat. It says (among other things) this:

> if you don‘t use the ref or out keywords, then arguments to methods
>   are passed by value.

The comment seems quite wrong to me. Is it?

(I posted part of the comment out of context: Here's the full comment:)

> The text says: "... but when a class instance is passed, a reference
>   is passed. ..." This is incorrect, as you can see in:
>
> C# Language specification Version 4.0 (a Microsoft free download)
>   5.1.4 Value parameters A parameter declared without a ref or out
>   modifier is a value parameter.
>
> So, in the example above, the class instance is passed by value, and
>   not by reference.

It is the full comment which is really confusing me... The class instance is passed by value and not by reference? Does that not imply that the instance bytes are pushed onto the stack?

Comment: No it is quite correct. Also there is no `val` counterpart to state it more directly. ByValue is the default and preferred mode.

Comment: I think if you read the entire post on the MS help page, it becomes more misleading, since it also states that:
"in the example above, the class instance is passed by value, and not by reference."

I think the class instance will not be passed by value (i.e. the data for the class will not be pushed on the stack), but only the reference to the instance will be pushed on the stack.

Comment: Matthew you are right, the comment is wrong but the part you quoted is correct... Not too late to Edit this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete comment is misleading. The object's reference is passed by value.

Comment: +1 If you understand this--I mean *really* get it--I think you'll be a notch above most programmers.

Comment: What is the misleading part? That's what it says.

Comment: @Henk I think the comment is accurate but it could be misunderstood since it doesn't specifically call out passing an object vs. an object-reference

Answer (score 5):

The comment is true. Without `ref` or `out`, the variable is passed by value. However, with objects, what you are passing by value *is* a reference.

The only time you would want to pass an object-reference by reference is if you are assigning a new object to the parameter within the method and you want that reassignment to affect the caller's copy of the reference.

You aren't ever really passing an *object* around. Instead you are passing around *references to* an object. With that in mind, this byval/byref business applies to the object-reference, not the object itself.

Jon Skeet has a [great post](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) about this topic.

Comment: You never pass an *object* by reference. You pass a *variable* by reference. You then don't assign a new *object* to the parameter - you assign a new *value* to the parameter. That value will be a reference, not an object. The reassignment will then affect the caller's variable - there's no "copy of the reference" here.

Answer (score 2):

The comment is completely correct. The confusion here is that value types and reference types are pretty much unrelated to passing an argument by value or by reference.

When you pass a value type as a non-ref parameter, you pass its value. That's clear enough. For a reference type, though, you are still only passing a value: **You are passing the *value* of the *reference* itself**.

If the parameter is `ref/out`, though, then you are actually saying that the parameter is an **alias for the variable that is actually being passed in**. In that case, it doesn't matter if it's a value type or a reference type; a reference to the variable is being passed, not just a value.