# passing address in c

Tags: c

In the following code example:

```
  typedef struct data{
  char ch;
  int n;
  int n2;


  }DATA;


 void Func3(DATA d){
    int sum;
    sum = d.ch + d.n;
    d.ch = 'c';
    d.n = 0x77;

 }


void Func4(DATA &d){
   int sum;
   sum = d.ch + d.n;
   d.ch = 'k';
   //d.n = 0x88;
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hlnst, HINSTANCE hprev,
      LPSTR lpCmd, int nShow)
{
  DATA dt;
  dt.ch = 'a';
  dt.n = 10;
  dt.n2 = 20;
 Func3(dt);
 Func4(dt);

 return 0;
}
```

Are Func3() and Func4() the same thing?
Are both functions pass-by-reference? 
Is there any difference between the two functions?

Comment: `void Func2(DATA &d){` is not valid (standard) C - what are you compiling this with?

Comment: In C there is no pass by reference

Comment: C doesn't have references. You can *emulate* it with pointers though.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: Are you talking about C or C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944774/difference-between-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference)

Comment: "is Func() and Func2() is the same thing?" - no; `Func2` could not even compile, unless this was C++ we were talking about and not C.

Comment: its compiling in c

Comment: What compiler are you using? As mentioned this code is not valid in C

Comment: just regular compiler it work fine

Comment: There is no "regular compiler". They ask you for exact compiler name and version.

Comment: And what command/compiler-flags you are using to compile it

Comment: Although based on the code edit and seeing you are using `int WINAPI WinMain` it seems safe to assume you are using a version of the Visual C++ compiler, in which case you are (with 99% certainty) compiling this as C++, not as C.

Answer (score 1):

**You are compiling this with a C++ compiler.** `DATA &d` is not syntactically correct in C.

In `Func`, the compiler essentially writes `DATA d = dt` before the function body is entered.

In `Func2` that "assignment" does not happen. The C++ compiler sets `d` to be a *reference* to `dt`. So changes to `d` in `Func2` are reflected in the caller as changes to `dt`.

In your *specific* case though, an optimising compiler will recognise that both functions are no-ops, and so will probably compile them out.

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no reference '&' type variables like in C++.

You have to pass the address to get the same affect. `FUNC2()` in C with 'd' as pass by reference will look like below:

```
void Func2(DATA *d){
int sum;
sum = d->ch + d->n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When in C there is used words "pass by reference" then it means that an object is passed to a function indirectly by means of a pointer to the object.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *sum, int x, int y )
{
    *sum = x + y;
}

void g( int sum, int x, int y )
{
    sum = x + y;
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    int sum;

    sum = 0;

    printf( "Before call of f sum = %d\n", sum );

    f( &sum, x, y );

    printf( "After call of f sum = %d\n", sum );

    sum = 0;

    printf( "Before call of g sum = %d\n", sum );

    g( sum, x, y );

    printf( "After call of g sum = %d\n", sum );
}
```

The program output is

```
Before call of f sum = 0
After call of f sum = 3
Before call of g sum = 0
After call of g sum = 0
```

The first function, function `f`. accepts the argument `sum` by reference that is using a pointer to `sum`. Thus after the function call the variable `sum` was changed.

The second function, function `g`, accepts the argument `sum` by value that is the function deals with a copy of the argument. Thus any changes of the copy do not influence on the value of the original argument.

In C++ apart from this meaning of the words "pass by reference" in the frames of C there is additional meaning because C++ introduced the notion of references like special kind of declarators and correspondingly defined the notion of the reference type.

Thus in C++ you can one more possibility to pass a value by reference. You may use a reference type. For example you could define a function for the example above the following way

```
void f( int &sum, int x, int y )
{
    sum = x + y;
}
```

In this case as the argument is passed by reference that is the corresponding parameter type is a reference type then the function will deal with the original argument instead of its copy.

.